# Ошибка YOAST плагина WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Здравствуйте!

В Wordpress выдаёт ошибку yoast, но у меня закончилась лицензия на PRO версию может из за этого быть?

Вот сама ошибка.

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of null
    at YoastSEO.App.updateLoadingDialog (yoast-seo-307.min.js:1)
    at YoastSEO.Pluggable._registerPlugin (yoast-seo-307.min.js:1)
    at YoastSEO.App.registerPlugin (yoast-seo-307.min.js:1)
    at new ExamplePlugin (yoast-plugin.js:11)
    at addPlugin (yoast-plugin.js:38)
    at yoast-plugin.js:5`

[image: ошибка]

Comment: Показывать код нужно текстом, а не картинкам.

Comment: @SeVlad какой именно код кинуть?

Comment: Вместо картинки должен быть текст.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of null
    at YoastSEO.App.updateLoadingDialog (yoast-seo-307.min.js:1)
    at YoastSEO.Pluggable._registerPlugin (yoast-seo-307.min.js:1)
    at YoastSEO.App.registerPlugin (yoast-seo-307.min.js:1)
    at new ExamplePlugin (yoast-plugin.js:11)
    at addPlugin (yoast-plugin.js:38)
    at yoast-plugin.js:5

Comment: В вопрос надо вставлять.

Comment: @HakobShaghikyan это точно не из-за лицензии.

Answer (score 0):

Это ошибка скорее всего из-за старой версии: вижу 307, а [акутальная - 4,3](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/). Я не знаю как лицензируется плагин и можно ли его обновить, но использовать старую в любом случае не стоит. 3.0.7 вышла более года назад.

Comment: Вы знакомы с плагином nectar shortcodes в теме Silent?

Comment: ? а какое это имеет отношение к вопросу? И вообще..